# Flutter 'setState' redraws the entire screen instead of just the widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

My code is as follows:

```
SfSlider(
                  minorTicksPerInterval: 0,
                  inactiveColor: Colors.grey[300],
                  tooltipShape: const SfPaddleTooltipShape(),
                  activeColor: _pictureQuality<500? Colors.deepOrange : _pictureQuality>500 && _pictureQuality<800? Colors.green : Colors.deepOrange,
                  edgeLabelPlacement: EdgeLabelPlacement.auto,
                    showLabels: true,
                    showTicks: true,
                    enableTooltip: true,
                    stepSize: 10,
                    showDividers: true,
                    interval: 10.0,
                    shouldAlwaysShowTooltip: false,
                    min: 50.0,
                    max:120.0,
                    value: _pictureQuality/10,
                    onChanged: (value) => setState(()=> _pictureQuality = value.toInt() * 10)),
```

I have a form with a slider. I am using the SfSlider plugin from pub.dev.

As you can see I call setState on pictureQuality which is only used (i.e _pictureQuality) in SfSlider, but my entire build method is triggering when I call the setState on that variable. How can I avoid this entire rebuild please?

Comment: Since the state is present in the parent of the SfSlider Widget, setting the state would cause the build method of the parent to be called.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `StatefulBuilder` like this:

```
StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (context, innerSetState) {
          return SfSlider(
              minorTicksPerInterval: 0,
              inactiveColor: Colors.grey[300],
              tooltipShape: const SfPaddleTooltipShape(),
              activeColor: _pictureQuality<500? Colors.deepOrange : _pictureQuality>500 && _pictureQuality<800? Colors.green : Colors.deepOrange,
              edgeLabelPlacement: EdgeLabelPlacement.auto,
                showLabels: true,
                showTicks: true,
                enableTooltip: true,
                stepSize: 10,
                showDividers: true,
                interval: 10.0,
                shouldAlwaysShowTooltip: false,
                min: 50.0,
                max:120.0,
                value: _pictureQuality/10,
                onChanged: (value) => innerSetState(()=> _pictureQuality = value.toInt() * 10));
        },
      ),
```

`StatefulBuilder` used when you have expensive widget and you don't want to update all the widget and want just update part of it. `setState` update the StatefulWidget's builder, but when you use `StatefulBuilder`, its give you another builder to update just its child.

more about [StatefulBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html).

Comment: Thanks I will try this. But I would like to know the reason for this behaviour as well, my understanding is that setState should only update widgets using the variable it is called upon

Comment: I was thinking about this and want to ask, as the entire build method is rebuild anyways, what is the difference between calling setState( () {} ) and SetState((){variable update})?

Comment: @Damandroid if you update the variable then call  setState is not difference than update the variable inside SetState. also remember using StatefulBuilder give you the power to avoid rebuilding  the entire build method.

Answer (score 0):

If your widget is heavy, you separate the context(create new widget) for SfSlider. Also, you can use `ValueNotifier` with `ValueListenableBuilder` if this is the only SfSlider is updating on current widget.